# NSDate formatter

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I try to convert a string to NSDATE with no luck unfortunately.

Friday, October 22, 11:26:45 ET 2010

I know the options for formatting (http://sree.cc/objective-c/nsdate-format-string-in-objective-c) but i cant get it to work.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"???????"];
```

anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Date Format Specifiers](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

So you'd probably need something like:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"eeee, MMMM dd, HH:mm:ss z yyyy"];
```

- `eeee` - Local day of week spelled out
- `MMMM` - Month spelled out
- `dd` - day of month with no leading zeros
- `HH` - hour of day (24 hour format)
- `mm` - minutes of hour (with leading zero)
- `ss` - seconds of minute (with leading zero)
- `z` - timezone (short wall time)
- `yyyy` - calendar year